# How can I debug Errno 10061 from smtplib in Python?

Tags: python, smtplib

At work, I have tools that send emails when they fail.  I have a blacklist, which I put myself on, so errors I make don't send anything but I recently needed to update this code and in testing it, found that I can't send emails anymore.

Everyone else is able to send emails, just not me.  I am able to use my regular email client (outlook) and I'm able to ping the mail server.  The IT guys aren't familiar with python and as far as they can tell, my profile settings look fine.  Just the simple line of `server =  smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)` fails with:
`# error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it #`

For info's sake, I'm running Vista with python 2.6, though nearly everyone else is running almost identical machines with no issues.  We are all running the same security settings and the same anti-virus software, though disabling them still doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to figure out why this is happening?  Maybe there is some bizarre setting on my profile in the workgroup?  I'm at a loss on how to figure this out.  All my searching leads to other people that didn't start their server or something like that but this is not my case.

Comment: Can you access it with *other* email clients?

Comment: As the error message says, the mail server is refusing your connection. There are many reasons it might do this. Your network administrator needs to sort this out. In any case, doesn't really belong here because it's not a programming question.

Comment: @UkuLoskit Yeah, firewall is disabled

Comment: The first thing you should do: > telnet smtpserver.com 25 (try to send an email manually with HELO ESMTP, etc). If it works, then at least you know the problem is in your code. Else, you know it's between your computer and the server.

Comment: @ignacio  Outlook is the only client supported, I've tried others in the past but wasn't able to get them to work.

Comment: @kindall  While it might be a network config issue, I thought that someone might have  insight into smtplib/sockets and if "refused" actually means refused.  If I'm way off base on my thinking, then I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) to see what's going on. It may give you more information.